# Example of function sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to construct an example of a pointwise limit of continuous functions that converges everywhere on the compact set $[-5,5]$ to a limit function that is unbounded on this set. Can you tell me if this works?

If $$f_n(x) = {nx \over 1 + nx^2}$$ then 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x = 0 \\
{1 \over x} & x \neq 0 
\end{cases}$$

is unbounded on $[-5,5]$.

Comment: I think you did a good job. If $x\neq0$ then$f_{n}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{nx}+x}\rightarrow\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @drhab Thank you for your comment!